# What am I?​‍​‍​‍​‍

Tags: riddle

> You can see me, but not feel me.
>   Sometimes I'm there, others not.
>   On a flat empty plane, in good light I won't be found.
>   Yet I will in every city and town.

**What am I?**

Comment: May be answer is Shadow

Comment: @narasimha *spoiler!*

Comment: Technically you can kind of feel a shadow if it's warm outside, the change in temperature.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since apparently nobody else wants to ... the intended answer is

> SHADOW.

*You can see me, but not feel me.*

> Shadows are easy to see, but can't usually be felt (well, they might block out the sun and make you colder ...)

*Sometimes I'm there, others not.*

> Shadows only appear when there's light to cast them.

*On a flat empty plane, in good light I won't be found.*

> But if there's light from all directions, then shadows won't be found.

*Yet I will in every city and town.*

> Shadows of buildings.

Answer (score 10):

This question is super broad, so instead of the somewhat bland

> shadow

I’m going to go maximally in the other direction (max lulz), and guess that you are

> An exotic dancer

I’m not certain the explanation would be entirely PG-13, so I’ll leave it to your imagination to fit the clues in.

Comment: Haha. PG-13, that made my day.

Comment: lol. This is wonderful.

Comment: "but not feel me" I disagree :P

Answer (score 1):

Yet another answer that works:

> Liquid nitrogen.

You can see me, but not feel me.

> Liquid nitrogen can be seen, but if you feel it your fingers will freeze and then you won’t be able to feel anything with those fingers.

Sometimes I’m there, others not.

> Liquid nitrogen doesn’t stay liquid if exposed to room temperature.

On a flat empty plane, in good light I won’t be found.

> Gases can become invisible in the right lighting.

Yet I will in every city and town.

> Liquid nitrogen has many practical purposes and is everywhere. Ex. Cooling system in computers

Answer (score 0):

You are

> the moon

You can see me, but not feel me.

> Because you're too high

Sometimes I'm there, others not.

> half the time you're not in the sky because you're on the other side of the earth

On a flat empty plane, in good light I won't be found.

> The plane is either the sky or a plane on earth, When there's light out the moon is invisible

Yet I will in every city and town.

> You can be found anywhere, depending on the hour of day